# erro ao conectar o Knex com o Banco oracle

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, knex.js

Estou tentando conectar o banco de dados ao nodejs com o Knex, porém ao realizar uma chamada na conexão obtenho o seguinte erro,

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin\oci.dll is not the correct architecture".

Minha string de conexão é esta.

```
client: "oracledb",
connection: {
  host : process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT
},
```

o banco não é localhost já está hospedado no servidor.

Comment: Esse erro nao pode ser causado por incopatibilidade da arquitetura do Node e do banco? [De uma olhada aqui](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#prerequisites), mas o que ele diz e que a arquitetura do node e do oracle tem que ser a mesma. Ele afirma na documentacao: Run `node -p process.arch` and make sure to use 64-bit or 32-bit Oracle client libraries to match the Node.js architecture.
" Use esse comando `node -p "process.arch`` para ver qual arquitetura do node voce usa

Comment: o problema foi resolvido porém com outra solução, o problema foi a instancia que não passei na conexão, por algum motivo o knex não estava reconhecendo o banco de dados como instância.

grato pela ajuda